# Generate table with repeating header row in PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I need to generate [this table](https://jsfiddle.net/e1fmofwg/) in PHP.

So this is my try:

```
$days = 7; 
$maxid = 7;
$startid = 1;

$html = "<table id='table1'>\n";
for ($i = 1;$i<=ceil($maxid/$days);$i++) {

    $html .= "<tr>\n";
    for ($j=1;$j<=$days;$j++)
        if ($startid <= $maxid)
            $html .= "  <td class='mark'>DAY ".$startid++."</td>\n";
        else 
            $html .= "  <td> </td>\n";

    $html .= "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
    for ($j=1;$j<=$days;$j++)
        $html .= "<td>Content</td>\n";

    $html .= "</tr>\n";
}

$html .= "</table>\n";
```

The problem is I do not how to insert the `MO TU WE TH FR SA SU` and the header isn't repeating every two rows.

Comment: I know this is probably a school project, but holy moly this reminds me why templating libraries are important. Barring that, your best bet is to debug your code. Since you have an idea of how you want these loops to run, you should test your assertions about the entrance and exit conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the MO, TU, etc to an array and iterate through it to pull the values for your repeating header.  From there, you can use the [Modulo Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to determine when two lines have been echoed and repeat your header:

```
$days = 7; 
$maxid = 7;
$startid = 1;

$dayLabels = array('MO', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA', 'SU');

$html = "<table id='table1'>\n";
for ($i = 1;$i<=ceil($maxid/$days);$i++) {

    $html .= "<tr>\n";
    if($i % 2 == 1) {
        foreach($dayLabels as $label) {
            $html .= " <th>$label</th>";
        }
        $html .= "</tr><tr>";
    }
    for ($j=1;$j<=$days;$j++)
        if ($startid <= $maxid)
            $html .= "  <td class='mark'>DAY ".$startid++."</td>\n";
        else 
            $html .= "  <td> </td>\n";

    $html .= "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
    for ($j=1;$j<=$days;$j++)
        $html .= "<td>Content</td>\n";

    $html .= "</tr>\n";
}

$html .= "</table>\n";
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. Actually the code do not output anything.

Comment: @popol,  The code (as in your example) is assigning the output to the `$html` variable.  If it is not producing output now, it would not have been producing it before.  How are you outputting the result of your existing code?